# Getting Akka actor to wait for external inputs without hanging other actors

Tags: java, akka, deadlock

Akka (**Java API**) here. Say I have two actors, `Watchdog` and `BlockingListener`. They both are injected with references to each other:

```
// WARNING!
// All code here is just Groovy-pseudocode
class Watchdog extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef blockingListener

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message in Init) {
            blockingListener.tell(new StartListening(), self())
        } else if(message in SomethingHappened) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class BlockingListener extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef watchdog

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message in StartListening) {
            while(true) {
                // Block and scan for input
                String event = waitForNextEvent()

                watchdog.tell(new SomethingHappened(event), self())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm concerned that the `while(true)` loop in the `BlockingListener` will prevent proper communication between the two actors. **Will it?** I'm worried that when `BlockingListener` is told to `StartListening`, it will:

1. Enter the `while(true)` loop; then
2. Make the `BlockingListener` thread hang/wait until an event (outside the actor system) occurs; then
3. *Attempt* to tell the `Watchdog` about the `SomethingHappened(event)`, **but...**
4. `Watchdog` will never receive the `SomethingHappened` because it is still waiting for its own `Init` message to finish being processed

Am I right? If so, what's the remedy here? How do we let `BlockingListener` listen for events outside the actor system and respond to them?

Comment: Don't use an actor to listen for events. Actors are meant to be reactive, not polling/blocking. Spawn a separate dedicated threads to `waitForNextEvent` and have it send that event to the actor.

Comment: Interesting, @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks and +1! Just curious here, then what about actors that need to make HTTP/REST calls or JDBC calls?

Comment: For HTTP, use an async client and have a success callback send an event back to the actor if it needs to do something with the response. For JDBC, this is a little more complicated because there is no async implement. You can dispatch to a dedicated thread pool or actor pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActorSystem` contains a default dispatcher which is essentially a thread pool, you can configure your own separate dispatchers but if you have not, the default dispatcher will be used.

When someone sends `WatchDog` the message `Init` it will be scheduled to run on one of the threads of the dispatcher, it will send the `StartListening` message to `blockingListener` and then return the thread to the dispatcher (as the receive method completes).

`BlockingListener` will however when someone sends it `StartListening` be assigned a thread, that it will keep forever and never return to the dispatcher. When it sends a message to `watchdog` it will depend on the number of available threads if `watchdog` will ever get to react on that message.

In general Akka is designed around not blocking, so you should avoid that as far as possible but there are some cases when it may be unavoidable to block.

What you should do in such cases is to isolate those actors onto a separate dispatcher (and prefer a thread pool based dispatcher over the default Fork Join Pool), this will make sure that your actor consuming one thread isn't a problem for the other actors of your system.

There is however still one more problem, even if you isolate the actor on its own thread pool and that is that since your actor is stuck inside the while loop (an actor will only ever execute in one thread at the same time) it will not react to getting sent the stop message, or even shutting down the actor system - the actor system will just hang.

This can be worked around by periodically breaking out of the loop, sending the actor a message to continue, which will then be added last in the actor mailbox and allow it to process other messages and possibly stop. This of requires the `waitForNextEvent` method to have some kind of a timeout, so that it will not block indefinitely.